# How to display current vm.map_max_map_count value?

Tags: virtual-memory, sysctl

I tried looking into */proc/sys/vm/max_map_count* file and it says 'empty' I have added a line `vm.max_map_count=16777216` in *etc/sysctl.config* and want to see if changes are applied.

I have certain problem with enlarging it being necessery to fix out of memory crashes in application and they still occur so i want to cross this one out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can’t open files under `/proc/sys` with tools which check their length; they appear as 0-byte files.

To check the current value, run

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

or

```
/sbin/sysctl vm.max_map_count
```